# Configuration admin and declarative osgi properties

Tags: java, osgi

Is it possible to be managed OSGI bundle properties with Configuration Admin? Which is the best practise about that?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is the purpose of Config Admin.

If you are looking for general documentation, I suggest the OSGi Specification or the book "OSGi in Action" (Richard Hall et al).

If you have already tried something and failed, please post details of what you did and what went wrong.

Comment: Is there any difference between properties defined like bundle properties and properties defined in persistent file?

Comment: @user1474038 I don't understand the question, sorry.

Comment: Is there any significance for Config Admin if the properties are defined in OSG-INF/activator.xml or in bundle.cfg?

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely possible. I typically using blueprint together with config admin service. It will give you properties like in spring with the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer. See: http://www.liquid-reality.de/x/G4Be for an example.